Is it possible to deserialize an nalgebra::DVector from a toml file?
Using Rust I would like to load a tool file where one of the fields should be deserialized to an nalgebra::DVector. Is this possible?
In my main Cargo.toml file I added:
nalgebra = { version = "0.33.0", features = ["serde-serialize"] }

I created a toml file with the following contents:
title = "My toml file."
[initial_condition]
dimension = 4
t_0 = 0.0
initial_state = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0]

I then tried to load the file with the code:
use nalgebra::DVector;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::fs;
use std::process::exit;
use toml::value::Array;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct InitialCondition {
    dimension: i32,
    t_0: f64,
    initial_state: DVector<f64>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MyData {
    title: String,
    initial_condition: InitialCondition,
}

fn main() {
    let filename = "read_dvector.toml";

    let contents = match fs::read_to_string(filename) {
        Ok(c) => c,
        Err(_) => {
            eprintln!("Could not read file `{}`", filename);
            exit(1);
        }
    };

    let data: MyData = match toml::from_str(&contents) {
        // If successful, return data as `Data` struct.
        // `d` is a local variable.
        Ok(d) => d,
        // Handle the `error` case.
        Err(err) => {
            // Write `msg` to `stderr`.
            eprintln!("Unable to load data from `{}`", filename);
            eprintln!(" Error: {}", err);
            // Exit the program with exit code `1`.
            exit(1);
        }
    };

    println!("title: {}", data.title);
    println!("initial_condition: {:?}", data.initial_condition);
}

This produced the output:
Unable to load data from `read_dvector.toml`
Error: TOML parse error at line 5, column 18
  |
5 | initial_state = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0]
  |                  ^^^^
invalid type: floating point `10.0`, expected a sequence

What am I doing wrong?

The 10.0 suggests it's expecting a nested list. DVector looks like it's some kind of matrix, does initial_state = [[10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0]] or initial_state = [[10.0], [20.0], [30.0], [40.0]] work?

I find Serialize implementations to be immensely valuable to determine that kind of question, what does a toml::to_string(&some_dvector) produce? That should give you a hint at what the Deserialize implementation expects, they typically are inverses of each other if possible.

FYI
Unable to load data from read_dvector.toml
Error: TOML parse error at line 5, column 17
|
5 | initial_state = [[10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0]]
|                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
invalid length 1, expected a tuple of size 3
Unable to load data from read_dvector.toml
Error: TOML parse error at line 5, column 26
|
5 | initial_state = [[10.0], [20.0], [30.0], [40.0]]
|                          ^^^^^^
invalid type: sequence, expected usize
let e = toml::to_string(&d);
println!("{:?}", e);
Err(Error { inner: UnsupportedType(Some("unit")) })

Not directly, TOML doesn't support everything necesseray to (de-)serialize a DVector from it's own Deserialize implementation. A DVector serializes to a tuple of (data, len, ()) and TOML has no way of expressing () so:
let other_data = InitialCondition {
    initial_state: DVector::from_vec(vec![]),
};
dbg!(toml::to_string(&other_data));

results in
[src/main.rs:25:5] toml::to_string(&other_data) = Err(
    Error {
        inner: UnsupportedType(
            Some(
                "unit",
            ),
        ),
    },
)

That being said, you can use #[serde(with = …)] to serialize with an intermediate Vec:
mod dvec_as_vec {
    use nalgebra::{DVector, Scalar};
    use serde::{de::Deserializer, ser::Serializer, Deserialize, Serialize};
    pub fn serialize<S, T>(v: &DVector<T>, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
        T: Scalar + Serialize,
    {
        v.data.as_vec().serialize(s)
    }
    pub fn deserialize<'de, D, T>(d: D) -> Result<DVector<T>, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
        T: Scalar + Deserialize<'de>,
    {
        let v = Vec::<T>::deserialize(d)?;
        Ok(DVector::from_vec(v))
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct InitialCondition {
    #[serde(with = "dvec_as_vec")]
    initial_state: DVector<f64>,
}


Thank you for your suggestion. #[serde(with = "dvec_as_vec")] works like a charm.
